# Exclude inline math from \DeclareMathSizes

Tags: fontsize, inline

I am using `\DeclareMathsizes` to display equations with a larger font than the rest of the text. But this is also applicable to inline math. Is there a way to exclude inline math from this command?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{20}{7}{7}
\begin{document}
    Some text before an inline math symbol $\alpha_1$ and some text after.\\
    
    \begin{equation}
        \alpha = \varepsilon + \vec{c}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: not really no, also never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph or before display math (or as here both) You are probably better to arrange for `\large` to go before the math displays rather than change the declaremathsizes settings

Comment: automatic change of style for inline is hard for several reasons not least things like `\sqrt{...}` or `\overarrow{...}` or `\begin{align}` that internaly use single-$ inline math even though to a human reader they look like part of a display. So what you mean by "inline math" and what TeX means are probably quite different.  So defining the few named display math constructs like `equation` to choose a larger size is much safer